# Find a control that doesnt have name

Tags: python, pywinauto

How can i get a control without any name.
When i inspect my window with inspect.exe I find informations about it:

- ControlType: UIA_PanelControleTypeId(0xC371)
- AutomationId: picLogo
- ClassName: windowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.33c0d9d
- ProcessId: 6024
- etc

I cant use the class name because it is not unique.
I've try every attribut of ChildWindow method without succes:

```
win.ChildWindow(class_name='').ClickInput()
```

I can't find the control with swapy.
I would like to find a other solution that using the coordonates of the button.

Thanks for your help

---

I achieve to use the control_id:

```
win.ChildWindow(control_id=66594).ClickInput()
```

But this id seem to change when the application restart.

---

Finally i achieve to access my control with "access name" given by SWAPY:

```
win.ChildWindow(best_match='WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.33c0d9d8').ClickInput()
```

or

```
win['WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.33c0d9d8'].ClickInput()
```

But is there a way to use the AutomationId given by the windows inspect tool

Comment: We're preparing pywinauto 0.6.0 soon with MS UI Automation support. Now it lives in UIA branch on GitHub (will merge to master in September). [Readme prototype](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/wiki/0.6.0-README-prototype). SWAPY isn't supporting UIA yet.

Comment: Good news thank you